# Does my finite state automaton accept a string iff it contains the given string as a substring?

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata, substrings

I am trying to write down the generalized form of the finite automata which accept strings which contain as a substring an arbitrary string. Here is what I have come up with — I was hoping someone could tell me if I've made any mistakes (i.e., if there are any "bugs" in my "design").

Let $\Sigma$ be an alphabet.

For any substring $S = s_{1}s_{2}s_{3}...s_{n}$, where, $s_i \in \Sigma$

The FSA that accepts strings containing $S$ as a substring is,

$Q=\{q_1, q_2, ..., q_n\} \cup \{q_0\}$

$F = \{q_n\}$

\begin{equation}
\delta=
\begin{cases}
(\_, s_1) &\rightarrow &q_1&\\
(q_i, s_{i+1}) &\rightarrow &q_{i+1} &\forall& i\neq 0\\
(q_i, s_k) &\rightarrow &q_0 &\forall& k\neq i+1 \land k\neq 1\\
(q_n, \_) &\rightarrow &q_n
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

$q_0$  is the starting state.

My rationale —

The states $\{q_1,q_2,...\}$ represent the state of having just seen symbol $s_i$. If we see the next expected symbol $s_{i+1}$, we go to $q_{i+1}$ and so on until we reach $q_n$ or end of input. $q_0$ represents having just seen a symbol that is not in $S$. An '_' represents any possible value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Remarks on your FSA

Your specification of the FSA is

- not finished. The transitions from states other than $q_n$ where the symbol read is not in $S$ are not defined.
- ambiguous.

  - What happens if $s_1=s_3$? Are $q_1$ and $q_3$ the same state?
  - Is the FSA deterministic or nondeterministic? It looks nondeterministic.

With the best intention to interpret your specification, consider the following example.

Let $S=aab$. The FSA will have four states, $q_0, q_1, q_2, q_3$.
Since $aaab$ contains $aab$ as a substring, the FSA should accept it.
On input $aaab$, the transitions of the FSA will be
$$ q_0\stackrel{a}{\to}q_1\stackrel{a}{\to}q_2\stackrel{a}{\to}q_0\stackrel{b}{\to}q_0.$$
However, $q_3$ is the only accept state.

#### Two easy solutions

Let $\Sigma$ be an alphabet. Let $S = s_{1}s_{2}s_{3}...s_{n}$ is the substring we want to find, where $n\ge1$, $s_i \in \Sigma$.

Let **the $n$-tail of a string $w$** be the longest suffix of $w$ not longer than $n$ symbols. It is $w$ if $|w|< n$, or the suffix of $w$ of length $n$ if $|w|\ge n$.

Here is a deterministic finite automaton $D$ that remembers the $n$-tail of $w$ when it has read $w$.

- For each string $w$ of length $\le n$, there is a state $q_w$.
- $q_\epsilon$ is the start state, where $\epsilon$ is the empty string.
- $q_S$ is the unique accept state.
- $\delta(q_S,\sigma)=q_S$.
- $\delta(q_w, \sigma)=q_{\text{the $n$-tail of }w\sigma}$ if $w\not=S$.

Here is a non-deterministic finite automaton $N$ that tries to match $S$ starting from every position. This NFA might have been your intention.

- $Q=\{q_0, q_1, \cdots, q_n\}$.
- $q_0$  is the start state.
- $q_n$ is the unique accept state.
- $\delta=\begin{cases}
  (\_, \_) &\to &q_0&\\
  (q_i, s_{i+1}) &\to &q_{i+1} &\forall i\lt n\\
  (q_n, \_) &\to &q_n
  \end{cases}$
  where $\_$ represents any possible value

It is straightforward to verify both automata accept a string $w$ if and only if $w$ contains $S$ as a substring.

#### Remarks on the problem

Constructing a finite automata which finds/accepts strings that contain a given string or does similar tasks is one of the most studied problems in computer science.  Some famous solutions are [Knuth–Morris–Pratt algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) and [Boyer–Moore algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string-search_algorithm). Can you find a better algorithm?